Why is my GoPro 10 telling me "Upgrade to a faster card (V30 or higher) to maximize performance." even though my card is V30?
My GoPro 10 is stopping video recordings and errors as follows:

RECORDING STOPPED: Your SD card can’t record with the current settings. Upgrade to a faster card (V30 or higher) to maximize performance.

Why is my GoPro 10 telling me "Upgrade to a faster card (V30 or higher) to maximize performance." even though my card is V30?

Images:
Error message on GoPro:

SD Card:


Your GoPro 10 might not be recognizing your V30 card due to compatibility issues, card corruption, or formatting problems. Try reformatting the card in the camera, updating your GoPro's firmware, or using a different V30 card from a reputable brand.

I reformatted the SD card and that fixed the issue:

I have no idea how the problem appeared in the first place: the same SD card worked fine with the GoPro for several year.

How much storage capacity was used when the error manifested, and had that storage level ever been reached before. The access level or order may have reached a feeble allocation unit spawning the error condition reformatting will put a fresh coat of paint over it or marked it off limits. Next possibility would be a non quick deeper formatting.

@civitas Thanks, I had recently removed most files, I think it only contained ~20GB of files. In the past I used >99% of the SD capacity.

The error could be as simple as a bump from the GoPro  rolling off the table slightly shifting it in the connector, or if on your last jump your parachute didn't open that abrupt stop and the bounce it took.

@civitas or maybe that bloated battery finally exploded?
